# How can i check for a keyhold in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to check whether arrow keys are being pressed on the PC and do something while it is being held down. For example if:

if arrow up is held down the console will print:
up,up,up,up..
-until released.
How can i do that? I tried some libraries but every one seems to only register a click but not a repeated hold..

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try ysing Pynput library and the keyboard listener.

I made a snippet for you to test, hope it helps!

```
from pynput import keyboard

def keyPress(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.up:
        print('Up pressed')

with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=keyPress) as kb:
    kb.join()
```

And don't forget to

```
pip install pynput
```

EDIT:

To see all keypresses you can try changing the callback to:

```
try:
    print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key.char))
except :
    print('key {0} pressed'.format(
        key))
```

The except block is just a workaround to show special keys too

Comment: Thank you for the immediate response and sorry for the noob question but where would you run this? When i run this in pycharm and press the up key i only move the cursor up in the code section.. When i run this through terminal it prints ^[[A...
Am i doing something wrong?(i am using mac)

Comment: You can run this script anywhere actually, i tested it using IDLE. As this snippet is just a Listener from the keyboard, all key presses should do the same functions, if you press UP it will still scroll up, but the keyboard will trigger the on_press callback and do the extra stuff you tell it to. To get a clearer view you can try the snippet i edited on the response

Comment: So i run the code with the edit you gave me but it only recognizes special characters like 'command, alt, shift' etc.
I am using a mac though..
I can't seem to make it work..

Comment: Perhaps its an IDE issue, try running it within IDLE (Python native editor) to see if it works out

Comment: I have run it through IDLE and its the same..Does it print every key normally for you?

Comment: Perfectly normal, when i'm pressing keys it show every single character (including Alt, shift keys, etc...), perhaps it's an OS divergence as i'm using Windows, and if i'm correct i'm afraid i won't be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about other platforms, but on Windows there is a library `conio` which you can use in C like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main() {
    while (1) {
        printf("%c", getch());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and with Cython you can use that `getch()` function the same way if you link against `conio` library.

This should be what [`getch`](https://pypi.org/project/getch/) package does for you in a cross-platform manner even with `termios` library on POSIX platforms.

If you don't want to use a non-standard library, then you'll end up with writing a platform dependent code such as `getch` package does for you:

```
import msvcrt
while True:
    print(msvcrt.getch())
```