# How can I find if someone is pressing a key repeatedly in python?

Tags: python

im trying to make a reaction test thing in python. basically you press enter to start and then at a random point between 5 seconds it will stop and you have to click enter again. it finds the time that it took for you to press enter. but i need a way to stop the person from just holding enter and cheating the program. help??

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
You seem to need to work through a tutorial on keypress events, and then design and code your system.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) is not a valid SO question. This suggests a collection of needs that are too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate question here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50956810/how-can-i-check-for-a-keyhold-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You could do also do this as a key release.

```
from pynput import keyboard


def on_release(key):
    print('Key released: {0}'.format(key))

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Make sure to also install the module:

```
pip install keyboard
```